# displaying jquery tooltip for each record in custom content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, jquery-tooltip

i am trying to show information for each record on tooltip using jquery tooltip for custom content. 
It does not show record for each item but only first record details. below is the view code which includes code and script as well.

i am looping through each item as

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Courses)
```

i want to display tooltip for each record when there is mouse hover on

```
<div class="item">
   <a href="" class="subitem">Detail</a>
</div>
```

**View**

```
<form id='familyform' method='post'>

 @using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("Summary", "SignupOrLogin", new { area = "Course" })))
 {      
            <div style="height:5px"></div>
            <label style="font-weight:bold">Select Course</label>
            <div style="height:5px"></div>
            <div style=" border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">   

                @foreach (var item in Model.Courses)
                {                      
                    <table style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:5px">
                        <tr style="height:22px">
                            <td style="width:50px">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkcourse@(item.Course.Id)" value="@item.Course.Name" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:5px">
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:300px">
                                <label style="font-size:smaller;color:#373737;">@item.Course.Name</label>

                            </td>                                
                            <td>
                                <label style="width:100px;font-size:smaller;color:#373737;">(£@item.Course.Fees)</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>                                                                                                                                       

                                    <div class="item">
                                        <a href="" class="subitem">Detail</a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="statusRollup">
                                       @item.Course.Name
                                       Start Date:  @item.Course.StartDate
                                       End Date : @item.Course.EndDate 
                                       Category:  @item.Course.Category
                                       Location: @item.Course.Location
                                       Fees: £ @item.Course.Fees
                                       Total Space: @item.Course.TotalSpace 
                                       Description: @item.Course.Description
                                    </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                                                                
                }
                </div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed"/>
</div>
 }
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

function select(sel)
{
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;        

    if (value == 'Family') {

        document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = "none";
    }        
}

 </script>

 <script>
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    }
});

$('.subitem').each(function () {
    // Get the contents of the next element with class=statusRollup
    var status = $(this).closest('.item').next('.statusRollup').html();
    $('.subitem').attr('title', status);
});
$('.statusRollup').remove();

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code

```
$('.subitem').attr('title', $('.statusRollup').remove().html())
```

`.html()` *gets the HTML contents of the **first** element in the set of matched elements* so you are assigning the content inside the first `<div class="statusRollup">` to all elements with `class=".subitem"`

Try

```
$('.subitem').each(function() {
  // Get the contents of the next element with class=statusRollup
  var status = $(this).closest('.item').next('.statusRollup').html();
  $(this).attr('title', status);
});
$('.statusRollup').remove();
```

Comment: I placed the same code as you suggested but nothing shows up on mouse hover.

Comment: Oops, slight error in my code (subitem is within another element). Will update in a moment

Comment: i am still waiting for your answer. i trying the code you sent but it does not work.

Comment: Do you see the change? `$(this).closest('.item').next(...` instead of `$(this).next(...`

Comment: Pleasure. Odd that you didn't get the notification - I edited it only a couple of minutes later. An alternative selector would be `$(this).closest('td').find('.statusRollup').html();` which might be a bit safer in case you change the order of the html (or add another element) in the table cell

Comment: thanks stephen. i will try it as well. yes very odd i did not receive any notification when you edit the answer.

Comment: sorry stephen it did not work actually . my mistake i did not check it for multiple records. it is displaying tooltip but never shows second record details. for each row it shows first record detail

Comment: Are you sure the html is as you have shown? I can create a sample fiddle a bit later

Comment: yes stephen, i double check it does not work for multiple records.

Comment: Doh, I'm an idiot - I not only got the first selector wrong, the second was wrong as well. Now updated. See also [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7kdw3m9/). Hover over the items (no tooltip) then click the button (tooltip now exists)

Comment: it worked like a charm for multiple records as well.

Comment: Now if I can just find that _Down vote yourself for stupidity_ button :)